# Extending set builder notation

Tags: notation, set-theory

Can we write this?
$  \{ x \in E \mid \Phi(x) \} \implies \{ x \mid x \in E  \} \land \{ x \mid   \Phi(x)  \}  
$

From Wikipedia's article about set builder notation $ \{ x \in E \mid \Phi(x) \} $ means the set of all values of  $ x$ that belong to some given set $ E $ for which the predicate, $ \Phi (x)$ is true .

Comment: What does it mean to take $\land$ of two sets?

Comment: @ConnorGordon I meant intersection

Comment: Aside the fact that $\land$ is a "logical and" (and $\cap$ is the set intersection), and the fact that $\{x\mid x\in E\}$ is just $E$... We should never use $\{x\mid\Phi(x)\}$. The set builder notation can only be used to extract a subset of an *existing* set - it is not allowed to use it on the "set of everything" because such set does not exist. In a nutshell, if what you tried was applied to $\Phi(x)\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}x\not\in x$ you get a paradoxical set which belongs to itself if and only if it doesn't (Russel's paradox). So we just don't do it.

Comment: See also: [Axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) (which is one of the schema-axioms of Zermelo-Frenkel axioms of set theory) and in particular the section "Unrestricted comprehension".

Comment: @StinkingBishop Is correct, but it's worth noting that it isn't, technically speaking, *incorrect* to use notation like $\{x\mid \Phi(x)\}$, but if you do so you run the risk of the object in question not being a set (instead you get a more general *class*), but at the elementary set theory level this likely isn't worth worrying about it too much detail.

Comment: Worth adding that *context* is everything. For example, $\{x\mid\Phi(x)\}$ can be used also if it is obvious that all the $x$ come from a pre-determined set (say $U$) so $\{x\mid\Phi(x)\}$ is a shorthand for $\{x\in U\mid\Phi(x)\}$.

Comment: There's a "mathematical grammar" issue going on here. Think of operations like $\implies$ and $\wedge$ as acting on **complete sentences**, while something like $\{x:\Phi(x)\}$ is just a **noun**. (What you've written is like "If duck, then bird and flying animal.")